# jquery populate into tables

Tags: jquery, html

I have this very basic html for tables.

```
 <table id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Sender</th>
            <th>Received</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I am using this code to populate my table's row

```
$.get('/currency', function(dreams) {
  dreams.forEach(function(dream) {
    $('<tr><td></td>').text(dream.jpy).appendTo('tbody#test')
    $('<tr><td></td>').text(dream.jpy).appendTo('tbody#test')
    $('<tr><td></td></tr>').text(dream.jpy).appendTo('tbody#test')
  })
})
```

my problem is, the row is not showing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing your closing `</tr>` on your first two lines.  Also the outer element of your thing is a tr, which doesn't have text.  The inner tds would have text.

Comment: Also the id `test` is on the table, not the tbody

Comment: `.appendTo("#test>tbody")`

Comment: Personally I would map all your data into an array of rows, and then append that array at the end.  Less DOM modifications.

Comment: please share dreams sample object, it looks like same value is populated for id,sender,receiver with dreams.jpy

Answer (score 0):

1. `tr` is not properly closed in first 2 statements
2. The output of `$('<tr><td></td></tr>')` will be `tr` not `td`,  so you are setting text inside `tr` not `td`
3. There is no element that matches `tbody#test` selector, because `tbody` doesn't have id `test`.

So, your solution is

```
$('<td />').text(dream.jpy).appendTo($('<tr/ >').appendTo('#test tbody'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Create row starting of loop using $('')
2. Get keys of each row to loop based on keys to set cell value in each column
3. Append row value to each cell using row.append($(''+dream[cellData]+''));

```js
    dreams.forEach(function(dream) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    var keys = Object.keys(dream)
            keys.forEach(function (cellData) {          
                row.append($('<td>'+dream[cellData]+'</td>'));
            });
            $('tbody').append(row);
    })
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gzbzqK

Answer (score -1):

thanks all for the help and comments. I have change it to something like this and is working

```
 dreams.forEach(function(dream) {
  $('<tr>').appendTo("#test>tbody");
  $('<td></td>').text(dream.jpy).appendTo('#test>tbody')
  $('<td></td>').text(dream.jpy).appendTo('#test>tbody')
  $('<td></td>').text(dream.jpy).appendTo('#test>tbody')
  $('</tr>').appendTo("#test>tbody");
})
```